# Is the double submit cookie pattern really safe?

Tags: cookies, csrf

I've searched a lot about csrf protection. Some of it mentioned double submit cookie pattern, and say that it has vulnerability about subdomain xss and http mitm attack.

But i can't figure out one thing, if the cookie and anti-csrf cookie is both automatically sent with request. then the attacker can of course get it. They don't need to perform attack in victim's browser but in their own browser.

image that:

***user visit a.com and get [cookie=user] [csrf-cookie=csrf]

then user visit b.com which is a website host by attacker.

the attacker get both cookie and just post a request with both cookies and set csrf-cookie in the header.***

Comment: The cookies in your imagined attack belong to the `a.com` domain, hence would _not_ be sent to `b.com`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen oh thank you , clearly i misunderstand how cookie works.

Comment: See, for example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies